# OpenJPA cannot read a persistence.xml document with JPA 2.1 and weblogic version 12.1.3

Tags: jpa, weblogic, openjpa

I am getting below error, I have deployed my ear file using JPA2.1,  weblogic version 12.1.3 and am using EclipseLink 2.6.4.

EclipseLink jars, persistence jar part of weblogic pre path, also I have set TOPLINK on weblogic server.
Note: I have also copied com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1 to weblogic pre path.

Plese guide some pointers on the below error.

This version of OpenJPA cannot read a persistence.xml document with
 a version different from "1.0". Found: version "2.1" in "zip:/tgwjpa/tgwjpa-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml".

Comment: Openjpa is being used as jpa provider and it doesnt support jpa 2.1. you say you are using eclipselink but evidently you arent.

Comment: ....and TopLink

Comment: Thanks for your replay, please let me know from where I can check this, do I need to copy any eclipse link jars to pre path?

Comment: please note our application was using kodo. I am trying to migrate it to latest jpa, my application seems still referring kodo reference. I have checked my ear file does not contain any kodo related jars.